# HTTP Erro 404 not found index.jsp

Tags: jsf, http-status-404

Estou tendo muitas dificuldades de executar esse projeto.

Ele diz que não está encontrando a página index.jsp. Sendo que porém, eu a apaguei, pois ela estava aparecendo e não o meu index.xhtml. Mas, agora o problema persiste. Troquei a configuração no web.xml para pegar as páginas com os formatos. .jsf, .xhtml e .html, mas, mesmo assim o problema continua.Segue a abaixo a Mensagem de erro do navegador.

HTTP Status 404 ? Not Found

Type Status Report

Message /plataforma/index.jsp

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.7

O console do servidor:
set 10, 2018 1:25:21 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:plataforma' did not find a matching property.
set 10, 2018 1:25:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.7
set 10, 2018 1:25:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Apr 3 2018 19:53:05 UTC
set 10, 2018 1:25:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         9.0.7.0
set 10, 2018 1:25:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
set 10, 2018 1:25:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
set 10, 2018 1:25:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
set 10, 2018 1:25:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre
set 10, 2018 1:25:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_162-b12
set 10, 2018 1:25:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
set 10, 2018 1:25:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\peric\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
set 10, 2018 1:25:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\peric\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.7
set 10, 2018 1:25:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\peric\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
set 10, 2018 1:25:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\peric\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.7
set 10, 2018 1:25:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\peric\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
set 10, 2018 1:25:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\peric\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.7\endorsed
set 10, 2018 1:25:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
set 10, 2018 1:25:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin;C:\Users\peric\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\peric\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\peric\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\peric\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\peric\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\peric\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;;C:\Users\peric\Desktop;;.]
set 10, 2018 1:25:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
set 10, 2018 1:25:22 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
set 10, 2018 1:25:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
set 10, 2018 1:25:22 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
set 10, 2018 1:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1782 ms
set 10, 2018 1:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
set 10, 2018 1:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.7
set 10, 2018 1:25:32 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
set 10, 2018 1:25:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
set 10, 2018 1:25:32 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.17 ( 20180411-2323 53e5a1509f6706550c6789ced710eb6ebf05fffd) for context '/plataforma'
set 10, 2018 1:25:32 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
WARNING: JSF1059: WARNING!  The com.sun.faces.verifyObjects feature is to aid developers not using tools.  It shouldn''t be enabled if using an IDE, or if this application is being deployed for production as it will impact application start times.
set 10, 2018 1:25:33 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2
set 10, 2018 1:25:39 PM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 6.2
set 10, 2018 1:25:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
set 10, 2018 1:25:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
set 10, 2018 1:25:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 17418 ms

E o meu web.xml:

http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

Bootstrap
    
        index.jsf
        index.xhtml
        index.html
    
    
        Faces Servlet
        javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
        1
    
    
        Faces Servlet
        *.jsf*
        .xhtml
        *.html
    
    
        Faces Servlet
        /faces/*
    
    
        primefaces.THEME
        bootstrap
    
    
        javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD
        client
    
     
  facelets.DEVELOPMENT
  true
 
 
  com.sun.faces.verifyObjects
  true

javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext
        resources.application

Comment: Tenta deletar o tomcat do eclipse e adicionar novamente

Comment: Obrigado Murilo Medeiros, mas, eu j[a resolvi esse problema, eu percebi que estava faltando uma dependencia no meu projeto, adicionei ao maven e resolveu.